# SSIS – can’t create connection manager to Access DB

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, ssis, etl, oledb

I need to pull data from an Access .accdb database and put it into a SQL Server table.  I am unable to create a connection to the Access database from an SSIS package.

- Visual Studio 2010 Pro - development tool.
- SQL Server Management Studio 2012 - database tool.
- Windows 10 Enterprise – OS on development PC.
- Office 365, 64-bit – productivity suite on development PC.

Several articles state to use the “Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider” to create a connection to the Access database.  I currently do not have this data provider.

The 2010 version of Visual Studio is a 32-bit product, and therefore needs a 32-bit connection to Access.  I have tried to install the “Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable”, but it will not install because I already have the 64-bit version of Access installed.

Any thoughts on how to install the 32-bit Access data provider – in the presence of a 64-bit version of Access.

Answer (score 0):

To install Microsoft Access database engine 32-bit alongside 64-bit installation, you should install it using the **passive mode**.

**Passive mode installation steps**

1. Open the Command Prompt by typing `cmd` in the Windows search box under the Start menu and selecting cmd.exe
2. Type the file path and file name of the 32-bit Access Database Engine 2010 install file, followed by a space and `/passive` (this runs the installation without showing any error messages).
3. Open the Registry Editor by typing `regedit` in the Windows search box under the Start menu and selecting `regedit.exe`
4. Delete or rename the `mso.dll` registry value in the following registry key:

   ```
    "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\FilesPaths"
   ```

*More details and screenshots are found in the link below*

- [How to install 64-bit Microsoft Access database engine alongside 32-bit Microsoft Office](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html)